# Import fails with file outside the root folder - webpack

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, commonjs

If I place a .js file outside the root folder where `package.json` is, and then I try to import it, it fails.

I can run `npx webpack` which seems to run without problems, but then the application fails with an error of the type "xxxx is not a function".

```
/* Content of webpack-example/src/main.js*/

//working fine when placing pepe.js inside `webpack-example`
import './../pepe.js';

//not working when placing pepe.js outside `webpack-example`
import './../../pepe.js';
```

Folder structure:

```
- pepe.js
- webpack-example/
---- src/
-------- main.js
---- dist/
-------- index.html
-------- main.js
---- node_modules
---- package.json
---- package-lock.json
```

Result of `npx webpack` when placing the file outside the webpack root folder:

[image]